# Numbers Mac Price Per Hour Formula

Tags: excel, macos, math, numbers, formula

I want to essentially calculate the price per hour. I have Column B, with time in it formatted like 01:10 00:45 00:10 etc. and i have a list of prices in column A. I want column c to list the cost per hour. Being below an hour would make it cheaper than the price in column A and being over an hour would make it higher etc.

```
|===A===|===B===|===C===|
|=Price=|Av Time|Cost PH|
-------------------------
|1202   |00:45  |       |
|1202   |00:45  |       |
|1202   |00:45  |       |
```

Comment: @pnuts just normal digits, like instead of (£)1202 it be 1500 in cell C

Comment: @pnuts *for example the values I'm requiring are a calculation of a based on b, cant you read the question? the formula would apply to any cell from column a and b onto c, seriously read lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel stores time as a fraction of a day, so 1 hour = 1/24.
Your formula (in `C2`) should be:

```
=A2/B2/24
```

Alternatively you can use `TIMEVALUE' function:

```
=A2/B2*TIMEVALUE("01:00")
```

Make sure to change `C` column format to currency/number/general

EDIT: I think the above functions calculate hourly cost, but after reading your description once more, I think you expect another result:

```
=A2*B2*24
```

or:

```
=A2*B2/TIMEVALUE("01:00")
```

Comment: Cheers will check it out and let you know bud!